# why is $T:R^2 \Rightarrow R^2$ $T(x,y)=(-y,x)$ an example of a linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Can someone give me an intuitive explanation why is $T:R^2 \Rightarrow R^2$ $T(x,y)=(-y,x)$ an example of a linear mapping?

Comment: What is the definition of a linear mapping? There is no intuition behind this definition unless you understand that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a rotation of $90°$ and rotations preserve linearity. More precisely,
\begin{align*}
T(x,y) =
\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1\\
    1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
    \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    x \\
    y
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    -y \\
    x
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Alternatively, you can prove that $T(a(x,y) + (w,z)) = aT(x,y) + T(w,z)$, which is true indeed:
\begin{align*}
T(a(x,y) + (w,z)) & = T((ax + w,ay + z)) = (-ay - z, ax + w)\\
& = a(-y,x) + (-z,w) = aT(x,y) + T(w,z).
\end{align*}